# knockout.js roadmap and future: will there be a knockout 4.0?

Tags: knockout.js

I know this question has been asked many times but the answers I found are inconclusive. ;-) We are refactoring a knockout-application and alternatives like react + mobx are under heavy consideration at the moment. So my question is: Will there be a knockout 4.0? knockout has not always caught up with new concepts (e.g. some HTML 5 widgets), its documentation still shows ES5-sample-code. Don't get me wrong. I like ko a lot but is it time for farewell?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question. The next [milestone on github](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/milestones) is 3.5.0.

Comment: OK, thanks! Where would be the right place? github?

Comment: Probably... Might also be better if you don't just ask for a version number but phrase the actual changes you're looking forward to. In some cases there might already be feature requests listed.